# Introduce delays of alternating value for synthesis on hardware

Tags: verilog, clock, delay, synthesis

My question here is with reference to [this question previously asked](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241130/introduce-delay-on-a-single-bit-signal-w-r-t-input-clock).
Currently, I am able to generate delays for each signal as desired.

Next, I want to generate different delays for alternate `vsync` rising edges.
Example:

- If it is the first rising edge of `vsync`, then generate delay equal to 4 clock cycles on output (i.e., `vsync_o`).
- If it is the second rising edge of `vsync`, then generate delay equal to 2 clk cycles on output (i.e., `vsync_o`).

So the delays I want on the output should alternate between 4 clock cycles and 2 clock cycles.

I am not able to figure out how to do this. I am currently initializing a counter which does not reset (so I can compute the number of vsync pulses).....but this will ultimately saturate. Is there a better method or am I missing something?

I have written the following code. Will this lead to any problems which can be avoided otherwise?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module Sync_Delay( clk_27,  vsync,   hsync,          
                            vsync_o, hsync_o );

 input clk_27;

 input wire vsync;
 input wire hsync;

 output reg vsync_o;
 output reg hsync_o;

 reg[20:0] v_bits;
 reg[2:0] h_bits;

 reg cnt = 0;

 always @ (posedge vsync)
 begin
     cnt = !cnt;
 end

 always @ (posedge clk_27)
    begin
    if (cnt == 0)
       begin
       vsync_o <= vsync;
       hsync_o <= hsync;
       end
    else
       begin
       vsync_o <= v_bits[20];
       v_bits <= {v_bits[19:0], vsync};
       hsync_o <= h_bits[2];
       h_bits <= {h_bits[1:0], hsync};
       end
 end
endmodule
```

I notice a difference in pulse width between the input and output signal, which is not desirable.

Comment: You only need a one-bit counter for vsync to tell you whether it's an "even" or "odd" count. Just allow it to roll over.

Answer (score 1):

From the other question, you already have a way of delaying the signal by between 1 and 4 clock cycles:

```
reg[3:0] bits;

always @ (posedge clk_27)
begin
    vsync_o <= bits[3]; //this was in the original code but actually makes it 5 cycles! But whatever.
    bits <= {bits[2:0], vsync};
end
```

So you can easily modify that to have two signals coming out, one with 4 cycles delay and the other with 2 cycles delay (hint: if bit 3 is 4 cycles of delay, which bi is 2 cycles).

Now you have two signals - one with 4 cycles of delay, and one with two cycles of delay. All that is needed then is a way to select which one is which. The word "select" implies you need a multiplixer - 2:1 in fact (two signals in, one out).

That means you also need something to drive the select line. Given it is 2:1, this is just a 1 bit control signal which you need to toggle every time there is a pulse. What do you know that can toggle? A flip-flop. To you need a flip-flop that toggles every time there is a pulse on Vsync.

The next question is, how do you detect a pulse on Vsync? Well, you see if there is a rising edge (or falling edge, or both). For that you need a rising edge detector. The structure is essentially:

```
reg delay;
always @ (posedge clock) begin
    delay <= in;
end
wire risingedge = delay && !in;
wire fallingedge = !delay && in;
wire bothedges = delay != in;
```

So you need the signal, plus the signal delayed by one clock cycle. You have `vsync`, and your `bits` register has the signal delayed by one clock cycle, so you already have all the signals you need to build an edge detector.

```
reg whichDelay;
always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset) beign
    if (reset) begin
        whichDelay <= 1'b1; //Start with a delay of 2 because on the first rising edge we will toggle.
    end else if (vsync && !bits[0]) begin
        whichDelay <= !whichDelay; //Toggle on each vsync input
    end
end

assign vsync_o = whichDelay ? bits[1] : bits[3];
```

And there you have it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will take a while to understand your answer. In the meanwhile, I have edited my question. Kindly provide a feedback. (Please note that this is the first time I'm coding using Verilog)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a better method. You must write your VHDL in gate level. Use a 2:1 mux to route your signal through two different delay element.

Concurrently use a counter to keep track of first and second rise of vsync. It should output its signal to the selector pin of the mux.